# How to stop an infinite while loop in Verilog

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, verilog

I am trying to give as input to a module the numbers: 0-127. This is why I am using a for or while loop. But, my problem is that the loop never ends. I am using Verliog, so I can not use break, whis is being used in System Verliog. I also use the EDA Playground to compile my code.
Do you know how can I solve this? 
Any help is appreciated.

```
module TOP();
  parameter ENDTIME=40000;  

  reg [63:0] inputdata1;  // is an 63-bit "register", or variable  
  reg [6:0] AddressR,AddressW;

  reg cen,clk=1'b0, R_W, reset;  
  wire [63:0] Data_Out;
  integer count;  
  wire Que_Full=0, Que_Last=0, Que_Empty=1;

  //call module for data I/O 
  process_data process_data( inputdata1, AddressR, AddressW, R_W , cen, clk, reset, Data_Out, Que_Full, Que_Last, Que_Empty);   


  always #10 clk=~clk;    //every 10 ->change

  initial
  begin
    $dumpfile("ALU.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0);

    $display("\t\ttime\tclk\t\t\tinputdata1\t\tData_Out\t\tAddressR");
    $monitor($time, "\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d",clk,inputdata1,Data_Out,AddressR);
    cen=1'b1;   //chip enabled 
    count = 0;
    R_W=1'b1;   //read
    AddressR=7'b0000_000;

    //input
     Execute loop till count is 127. exit at count 128
     for (count=0; count < 128; count=count+1)   //while(count<128)
       #10
      begin 
           inputdata1 = count;
           AddressR=AddressR+7'b0000_001; 
           //count = count + 1;

      end 

    #ENDTIME  
    $display("-------------- THE SIMULATION FINISHED ------------");  
    $finish; 

   end

endmodule
```

The results that I am getting from the Icarus compiler are:

```
   time   clk           inputdata1      Data_Out        AddressR
                   0    0                      x                       x      0
                  10    1                      0                       x      1
                  20    0                      1                       x      2
                  30    1                      2                       x      3
                  40    0                      3                       x      4
                  50    1                      4                       x      5
                  60    0                      5                       x      6
                  70    1                      6                       x      7
                  80    0                      7                       x      8
                  90    1                      8                       x      9
                 100    0                      9                       x     10
                 110    1                     10                       x     11
                 120    0                     11                       x     12
                 130    1                     12                       x     13
                 140    0                     13                       x     14
                 150    1                     14                       x     15
                 160    0                     15                       x     16
                 170    1                     16                       x     17
                 180    0                     17                       x     18
                 190    1                     18                       x     19
                 200    0                     19                       x     20
                 210    1                     20                       x     21
                 220    0                     21                       x     22
                 230    1                     22                       x     23
                 240    0                     23                       x     24
                 250    1                     24                       x     25
                 260    0                     25                       x     26
                 270    1                     26                       x     27
                 280    0                     27                       x     28
                 290    1                     28                       x     29
                 300    0                     29                       x     30
                 310    1                     30                       x     31
                 320    0                     31                       x     32
                 330    1                     32                       x     33
                 340    0                     33                       x     34
                 350    1                     34                       x     35
                 360    0                     35                       x     36
                 370    1                     36                       x     37
                 380    0                     37                       x     38
                 390    1                     38                       x     39
                 400    0                     39                       x     40
                 410    1                     40                       x     41
                 420    0                     41                       x     42
                 430    1                     42                       x     43
                 440    0                     43                       x     44
                 450    1                     44                       x     45
                 460    0                     45                       x     46
                 470    1                     46                       x     47
                 480    0                     47                       x     48
                 490    1                     48                       x     49
                 500    0                     49                       x     50
                 510    1                     50                       x     51
                 520    0                     51                       x     52
                 530    1                     52                       x     53
                 540    0                     53                       x     54
                 550    1                     54                       x     55
                 560    0                     55                       x     56
                 570    1                     56                       x     57
                 580    0                     57                       x     58
                 590    1                     58                       x     59
                 600    0                     59                       x     60
                 610    1                     60                       x     61
                 620    0                     61                       x     62
                 630    1                     62                       x     63
                 640    0                     63                       x     64
                 650    1                     64                       x     65
                 660    0                     65                       x     66
                 670    1                     66                       x     67
                 680    0                     67                       x     68
                 690    1                     68                       x     69
                 700    0                     69                       x     70
                 710    1                     70                       x     71
                 720    0                     71                       x     72
                 730    1                     72                       x     73
                 740    0                     73                       x     74
                 750    1                     74                       x     75
                 760    0                     75                       x     76
                 770    1                     76                       x     77
                 780    0                     77                       x     78
                 790    1                     78                       x     79
                 800    0                     79                       x     80
                 810    1                     80                       x     81
                 820    0                     81                       x     82
                 830    1                     82                       x     83
                 840    0                     83                       x     84
                 850    1                     84                       x     85
                 860    0                     85                       x     86
                 870    1                     86                       x     87
                 880    0                     87                       x     88
                 890    1                     88                       x     89
                 900    0                     89                       x     90
                 910    1                     90                       x     91
                 920    0                     91                       x     92
                 930    1                     92                       x     93
                 940    0                     93                       x     94
                 950    1                     94                       x     95
                 960    0                     95                       x     96
                 970    1                     96                       x     97
                 980    0                     97                       x     98
                 990    1                     98                       x     99
                1000    0                     99                       x    100
                1010    1                    100                       x    101
                1020    0                    101                       x    102
                1030    1                    102                       x    103
                1040    0                    103                       x    104
                1050    1                    104                       x    105
                1060    0                    105                       x    106
                1070    1                    106                       x    107
                1080    0                    107                       x    108
                1090    1                    108                       x    109
                1100    0                    109                       x    110
                1110    1                    110                       x    111
                1120    0                    111                       x    112
                1130    1                    112                       x    113
                1140    0                    113                       x    114
                1150    1                    114                       x    115
                1160    0                    115                       x    116
                1170    1                    116                       x    117
                1180    0                    117                       x    118
                1190    1                    118                       x    119
                1200    0                    119                       x    120
                1210    1                    120                       x    121
                1220    0                    121                       x    122
                1230    1                    122                       x    123
                1240    0                    123                       x    124
                1250    1                    124                       x    125
                1260    0                    125                       x    126
                1270    1                    126                       x    127
                1280    0                    127                       x      0
                1290    1                    127                       x      0
                1300    0                    127                       x      0
                1310    1                    127                       x      0
                1320    0                    127                       x      0
                1330    1                    127                       x      0
                1340    0                    127                       x      0
                1350    1                    127                       x      0
                1360    0                    127                       x      0
                1370    1                    127                       x      0
                1380    0                    127                       x      0
                1390    1                    127                       x      0
                1400    0                    127                       x      0
                1410    1                    127                       x      0
                1420    0                    127                       x      0
                1430    1                    127                       x      0
                1440    0                    127                       x      0
                1450    1                    127                       x      0
                1460    0                    127                       x      0
                1470    1                    127                       x      0
                1480    0                    127                       x      0
                1490    1                    127                       x      0
                1500    0                    127                       x      0
                1510    1                    127                       x      0
                1520    0                    127                       x      0
                1530    1                    127                       x      0
                1540    0                    127                       x      0
                1550    1                    127                       x      0
                1560    0                    127                       x      0
                1570    1                    127                       x      0
                1580    0                    127                       x      0
                1590    1                    127                       x      0
                1600    0                    127                       x      0
                1610    1                    127                       x      0
                1620    0                    127                       x      0
                1630    1                    127                       x      0
                1640    0                    127                       x      0
                1650    1                    127                       x      0
                1660    0                    127                       x      0
                1670    1                    127                       x      0
                1680    0                    127                       x      0
                1690    1                    127                       x      0
                1700    0                    127                       x      0
                1710    1                    127                       x      0
                1720    0                    127                       x      0
                1730    1                    127                       x      0
                1740    0                    127                       x      0
                1750    1                    127                       x      0
                1760    0                    127                       x      0
                1770    1                    127                       x      0
                1780    0                    127                       x      0
                1790    1                    127                       x      0
                1800    0                    127                       x      0
                1810    1                    127                       x      0
                1820    0                    127                       x      0
                1830    1                    127                       x      0
                1840    0                    127                       x      0
                1850    1                    127                       x      0
                1860    0                    127                       x      0
                1870    1                    127                       x      0
                1880    0                    127                       x      0
                1890    1                    127                       x      0
                1900    0                    127                       x      0
                1910    1                    127                       x      0
                1920    0                    127                       x      0
                1930    1                    127                       x      0
                1940    0                    127                       x      0
                1950    1                    127                       x      0
                1960    0                    127                       x      0
                1970    1                    127                       x      0
                1980    0                    127                       x      0
                1990    1                    127                       x      0
                2000    0                    127                       x      
                     .......
```

Comment: @toolic I had this line for the while loop , the for loop does not need it

Comment: @toolic Because which loop I am gonna use (for or while ), is not my problem. I have tested my code with both loops and they run infinitely

Comment: @toolic So if I delete this line :  ```#ENDTIME```, the simulation will work right?

Comment: @toolic When I delete #endtime, the simulation ends after I have given as input the number: 127, which is what I want. With #endtime, the loop is infinite

Comment: @toolic yes , I am using eda to run the code

Comment: @toolic only the top: https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5SZU and https://www.edaplayground.com/x/28xR with some other code , In both examples the results are the same for me

Answer (score 1):

**The original Question:**

You need to remove this line:

```
       count = count + 1;
```

The `for` loop automatically increments `count` for you.  You should not modify the loop iterator variable within the loop.

---

**After the Question was significantly changed:**

The loop ends when you hit 127. Then you add a long delay after the loop, where count remains at 127, as expected. Perhaps you thought the simulation was in an infinite loop because your log file kept showing 127 for count. Then the sim ends at time 41270.  You confirmed this behavior on EDAplayground.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign count with reg.

reg [6:0] count;

Comment: You have declared parameter ENDTIME=40000; if that is, after 40000 simulation (usally 1ns/1ps that means that 40000ns) time then simulation finishes.
If you clear it out, you will most likely achieve what you desire.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to run simulation as ENDTIME. But, input data does not change. So, you can say that  "count < 128 ? count = count + 1 : count = 0 ". Until the simulation ends, the count variable changes  0,1,2..,127, 0, 1, 2.. and goes on.